# Perl: substitute scalar with element of array for that index

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, substitution

I have the following code

```
    #!/bin/perl

    $prevjob[1]= 'PREVJOB1';
    $prevjob[2]= 'PREVJOB2';
    $prevjob[3]= 'PREVJOB3';
    $line[2]= '(s1&s3)|s2';
    if($line[2]) {
    #this will work for first replacement, but its not working,
            $line[2]=~ s/s([0-9])/s${prevjob[\1]}/;
            print $line[2];
    }
```

I want to use the numbers in the scalar as indexes and substitute the number with @prevjob's element at that index.

I want to replace `s/s([0-9])/s${prevjob[\1]}/`
My expected output is :

```
(sPREVJOB1&sPREVJOB3)|sPREVJOB2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. Looks like i needed `s/s([0-9])/s${prevjob[$1]}/;`

`$1` instead of `\1`

Comment: Yes, `\1` is deprecated. Use `$1` instead.